# How to create a responsive faded effect on an image

Tags: css, box-shadow

I'm trying to achieve a faded effect on the left side and bottom of an image, like this result:

[image]

I tried it like this: `box-shadow: inset 0 0 85px 50px #f5f7fc` but on Firefox it doesn't work the way you expect. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider gradient like this:

```css
.img {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(to top, #f5f7fc 10%, transparent 30%),
  linear-gradient(to right, #f5f7fc 10%, transparent 30%),
  url(https://lorempixel.com/400/200/) 0 0 /cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code, here I have added gradient "before and after" in css.

HTML:

```
<div class="gradient">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="images" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.gradient {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.gradient:before,
.gradient:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

.gradient:before {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    bottom: 0;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gradient:after {
    width: 25%;
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```